# Quicky output selection of video frames using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to extract, say, 10 video frames from a given video file using ffmpeg, ideally uniformly distributed throughout the video. I know this can be done in a few ways, for example

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1/10 out%03d.jpg
```

will output one image every 10 seconds. However, this is too slow for my liking and scales proportionally with the length of the video. I have read a bit about ffmpeg's seeking capability, for example

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 out001.jpg
```

will very quickly seek to the 5th second of the video and extract one frame. However I haven't come across a way to seek to multiple locations in the video without calling the above command repeatedly at various times.

Is there a quicker way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you know the duration of the video?

Comment: I can obtain that very quickly with ffmpeg/ffprobe, so the amount of time to 'distribute' the selected frames by is not an issue. I would just like to do it more quickly than the above methods I posted.

Comment: Only the `ss` before `-i` does a fast seek. `ss` after or use of any filter, like `select` will take more time as all frames are decoded, evaluated and then kept or discarded.

Comment: I believe in newer version of ffmpeg -ss after -i is now just as quick. Anyways, I have -ss before -i, but I am looking for a quicker solution, such as seeking multiple times but with only one ffmpeg command.

Comment: *ffmpeg -ss after -i is now just as quick* - No, it's not and it can't be.

Comment: Hmmm yes apparently so. My mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a long command, this can be done

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i input.mp4
       -ss 00:01:05 -i input.mp4
       -ss 00:03:05 -i input.mp4
       -ss 00:40:05 -i input.mp4 
       -map 0:v -frames:v 1 out001.jpg
       -map 1:v -frames:v 1 out002.jpg
       -map 2:v -frames:v 1 out003.jpg
       -map 3:v -frames:v 1 out004.jpg
```

Comment: can you explain what this means